# Passing data to fragments while using NavigationUI

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android programming. I get regularly help from SO.

I have three items in tool bar menu and based on selection of menu item the app traverses to the relevant fragment. I want to pass data to the fragment. Based on the info in SO and also Android official website, I have created arguments in navigation graph and set values in Main activity. But I do not know how to use this with NavigationUI.

Navigation graph is as follows:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/helpFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ptimer.HelpFragment"
        android:label="About"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_helpFragment_to_LauncherFragment"
            app:destination="@id/LauncherFragment">
            <argument
                android:name="help_title"
                app:argType="string" />
            <argument
                android:name="help_desc"
                app:argType="string" />
            <argument
                android:name="help_image"
                app:argType="string" />
        </action>
    </fragment>
```

The main activity method is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("help_title", help_title);
            bundle.putString("help_desc", getResources().getString(R.string.pBasics_desc));
            bundle.putString("help_image", "basic");

        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I want your help to know how to use the bundle in NavationUI. Or is there any other method to pass data to a fragment when menu is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have created a bundle object but you haven't used it anywhere while passing data.
I would suggest you to use `SafeArgs` as you are already using `Navigation Component`.

You'll need to add some dependencies for safe args but once you add that it'll be very simple. As soon as you add any directions there will be a directions class generated and in that it will require arguments (if there are any mentioned in you graph)

You can get a detail explanation and sample for safe args [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#define_destination_arguments).

In any case if you still wants to pass data using bundle then you can have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#bundle).

Instead of using `OnOptionsItemSelected` you should use :-

```
 override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.YourItemId -> {
                yourNavController.navigate(YourDirections.yourAction())
            }
            else -> navController.navigate(item.itemId)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Hanif, thanks for your guidance. But could not make out how to pass view in `   Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);` as the code is in activity.  I tried view of the home fragment in the main activity and got runtime error.

Comment: Can you please add the code where are you doing navigation ?

Comment: Code is from MainActivity  `    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.helpFragment) {
            LFDirections.PassData action = LFDirections.passData();
            action.setHelpTitle("Mahat");
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
       }
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }`

Comment: @BMG I have updated my answer

Comment: @Hanif, Getting error that `onNavigationItemSelected()` is not overriding in the super class.